# passing value through url with question mark (?) not working in mobile

Tags: php, url, redirect

I have a page that takes value through url and redirects to other web page. The url looks like :

http://www.mywebsite.com/offer.php?email_id=abcd@yahoo.com&offer_id=1

Now the offer.php takes email_id and offer_id and redirects it to other web page; e.g. to http://www.abcdef.com.

The url is working perfectly in desktop web browser and in my android mobile. But in symbian browsers and iphone browsers, it just shows that url not found!!

Can anyone suggest me an way through which I can overcome this issue?

Comment: buy me an iphone and I will test for you

Comment: this is awkward, you are passing parameters to the server and it's server side where all the processing takes place. Are you using the same network to connect or are you using your mobile's 3G/Data Plan/etc to access the page, there may be a proxy playing funky with your site. can you share your webpage URL?

Comment: The process.php takes email and offer id. Email and offer id, and link to redirect are stored in the database. Offer.php takes the email and offer id and fetches out the url to redirect, and just redirects it by using header("location: http://www.abcd.com"); This is the total process @Josh

Comment: @wrongnumber Thats the problem! My internnet connection for mobile is ok. While android works, iphone and symbian does not work! thats so creepy for me!

Yes, the url link is : "http://www.little-pie.com/offer.php?email_id=anteomnio@yahoo.com&offer_id=1"

Comment: when you have a bug in your code. its impossible to help without seeing it. even after we know what you want it to do.

Comment: @Josh

Here's the code that redirects:

    $selectLink = mysql_fetch_assoc($selectLinkResult);
$link = $selectLink['offer_link'];
echo "<script>window.location = \"".$link."\"</script>";

Comment: that's why, don't do it with js, use php header()

Comment: I've also tested with header("location:url"); But it is not working too in symbian and iphone!

Comment: php is server-side its browser agnostic

Comment: @Dagon the browser still has to support/understand the redirect. although i don't think that's the problem here.

Comment: What iphone shows for the url http://www.little-pie.com/offer.php?email_id=anteomnio@yahoo.com&offer_id=1

"Your URL entry for www.little-pie.com/offer.php?email_id=anteomnio@yahoo.com was not found.

Did you mean http://www.little-pie.com/offer.php?email_id=anteomnio@yahoo.com ?

Remember the entered URL needs to be complete and include the protocol (eg. http://)."

Comment: Error status code (502).. requested item could not be loaded for symbian

Comment: 502 is a network error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@AnteOmnio the links is not working on my laptop just displays a blank page. please try the following link on all your devices and let me know the results please, It's a simple test to see if there is something wrong with network/devices/code

the code for the following link is:

```
<?php

echo "Welcome To Test Offer Page<br><br>";

if(!$_GET){
    echo "I have no details of who you are!";
}else{
    echo "Your Email ID is <b>".$_GET["email_id"]."</b> and you're Offer ID id <b>".$_GET["offer_id"]."</b>";
}
```

http://clients.nishantarora.in/projects/AnteOmnio/offer.php?email_id=anteomnio@yahoo.com&offer_id=1

Comment: Hi,
Sorry for the late reply. Yes, I have tested the link you provided with android(ics) and showing the result properly. Both for iphone 5, and Nokia 3300, it is working.

Comment: @AnteOmnio happy to know that... :) hope it solved your problem. Please mark it as complete.

Answer (score 0):

you are using java-script to redirect the user which has its set of issues on mobile devices, instead you should be using a server side redirect.

`header('Location: '.$url);`

when using header to redirect make sure that there is no output before (not even white-space or new line) or it won't work